# How to separate numbers and characters with RegEx?

Tags: c#, regex

I have following regulare expression string

```
(\d+)(((.|,)\d+)+)?(ms|s| ms| s)
```

It validates if user entered a correct string for milliseconds and seconds.
Example of possible values are

- 100ms
- 100s
- 100 ms
- 100 s
- 52.55 s

for further operations I need to seperate out the string and the number, for example, if value entered is `123.45ms` I should get `123.45` and `ms`.

As of now I'm only getting the number and string is lost!

I can split the numbers and string in two different steps, but I'm interested in doing at once, any suggetions how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use groups:

```
        string s = "123.45ms";
        Match m = Regex.Match(s, @"(\d+([.,]\d+)?) *(ms|s)");

        if (m.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[3]);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are very close. You are already specifying match groups. Have a look at [Match.Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are indeed getting the number and unit, the problem is it's getting put into a larger array element than you think. I would suggest amending your regex to:

```
(\d+)([\.|,]\d+)?\s?(m?s)
```

Now you will have your number's integer at 1, decimal if it exists at 2 (or if not it will be empty) and unit at 3. It's a little tidier and you won't get the space in your unit anymore.

Alternatively you could use:

```
(\d+[\.|,]\d+|\d+)\s?(m?s)
```

if you always want your number at index 1 and unit at 2.

Comment: Don't put `|` in character classes unless you mean it, also no need to escape `.` in them.