# How to get prefix, value and exponent by RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

This is an extension to the following question: [How to separate numbers and characters with RegEx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321771/how-to-separate-numbers-and-characters-with-regex)

**This is the text to be examined:**

```
"min:   42.4ms"

"typ:   42,8ms"

"max:   43,2 ms"
"max 43,2 s"
"blublub_typ = n.a."
"bla_max = 2500,0 µs"
"jubdi,"dupp_min = 100,0 µs"
```

**And I want to find this, divided in three groups:**

```
(min) (42.4) (ms)
(typ) (42,8) (ms)
(max) (43,2) (ms)
(max) (43,2) (s)
(typ) (n.a.)
(max) (2500,0) (µs)
(min) (100,0) (µs)
```

As I am only interested in the right RegEx pattern, it is just a way to describe content of each resulting group by brackets.

**This is what I tried for example:**

```
(min:|max|typ|max:)+\s?(\d+[.,]\d+|\d+)\s?(µs|ms|s)
```

**Problems:**

But I do not know how to ignore any kind of text in front of the interesting part. Further I do not know how to ignore any equal operators or colons and what ever could come instead of them, by not mentioning all possibilities in the first group.

Can anyone help me?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use RegexStorm when testing .Net regexes since the behavior is not exactly the same as the flavors provided by Regex101.

I would use this regex ([demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=.*%28%3F%3Ctype%3Emin%7Cmax%7Ctyp%29%5B%20%3A%3D%5D%2B%28%3F%3Cvalue%3E%5Cd*%5B%2C.%5D%3F%5Cd*%29%5Cs%3F%28%3F%3Cunit%3E.*%29%22&i=%22min%3A%2042.4ms%22%0D%0A%0D%0A%22typ%3A%2042%2C8ms%22%0D%0A%0D%0A%22max%3A%2043%2C2%20ms%22%0D%0A%0D%0A%22max%2043%2C2%20s%22%0D%0A%0D%0A%22blublub_typ%20%3D%20n.a.%22%0D%0A%0D%0A%22bla_max%20%3D%202500%2C0%20%C2%B5s%22%0D%0A%0D%0A%22jubdi%2C%22dupp_min%20%3D%20100%2C0%20%C2%B5s%22)):

```
.*(?<type>min|max|typ)[ :=]+(?<value>\d*[,.]?\d*)\s?(?<unit>.*)"
```

Which uses named capture group allowing to understand a bit more what it does. It gives you the following matches:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Thomas, this is a very good solution, as it can also handle with ".n.o" and further gives names to the groups!

Comment: How could it work with "bla_max = 2.500,0 µs" as well as with "bla_max = 2500,0 µs"?  (with and without additional '.')

Comment: @Tinitus change it to `.*(?<type>min|max|typ)[ :=]+(?<value>[.\d]*[,.]?\d*)\s?(?<unit>.*)"`

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
.*(min|max|typ)[\S|\s]=?\s?(\d*.?\d*)\s?(.*)
```

You can test it at the following URL https://regex101.com/r/HNQ743/1

Comment: Is `[\S|\s]` functionally different from `.` ?

Comment: \S means "Not Whitespace". \s means "Whitespace".

Comment: Thanks Neekoy! Unfortunatelly your solutions seems to output different. E.g. "BLUB-807,\"TTT_zu_io43_max = 2500, 0 µs" --> (max)(2500,)(0 s), whereas "min:\t11ms" --> (min)(11m)(s). Am I am right?

Comment: Good question about [\S|\s] and . - they should behave in the same way, however it doesn't match for me that way for some reason. Although separately, a dot matches both the : and the space character.

Comment: As of the results on your end, it's most likely that the C# regex engine is a bit different than the other ones - they all are. I have never in my life written in C# so it might be best to update the OP with this information and someone who's done Regex in C# might have some input because I can't seem to find a reason.